# Помогите найти ошибку в Jquery!

Tags: php, html, jquery

Я начал изучать Jquery, и у меня появилась проблема. После получения ответа с `content.php` в начале строки появляется `п»ї`. Почему?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ajax</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function funcBefore() {
    $("#content").html ("Загрузка...");
}
function funcSuccess(data) {
    $("#content").html (data);
}
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#load").bind("click", function (){
            $.ajax ({
                url: "content.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: ({name: "admin"}),
                dataType: "html",
                beforeSend: funcBefore,
                success: funcSuccess
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="load" style="cursor: pointer;">Загрузить страницу</p>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Содержание `content.php`:

```
<?php
    echo "string"
?>
```

Comment: Ошибка не в jQuery, а в сервере, лишний символ попадает в ответ сервера как я понял, смотрите ошибку в файле `content.php`

Comment: В content.php ошибок нет. <? echo "string" ?>

Comment: Я использую локальный сервер Denwer

Answer (score 7):

п»ї - это BOM - метка Юникода. 
Попробуйте пересохранить content.php в кодировке utf-8 без BOM

**UPD** А вообще, если есть возможность, для локальной разработки под Win лучше использовать OpenServer, по-моему. В отличии от того же Denwer - поддерживается и развивается.

Comment: Можно поподробнее? Что такое BOM?

Comment: Сохранение в кодировке utf-8 не помогло. Как исправить?

Comment: @smokenmoon плюсую! он даже проще в настройке.

Answer (score 0):

1) Не вижу тега meta с кодировкой в head
2)  У денвера есть проблема с кодировкой. Он по дефолту использует windows-1251. Попробуйте изменить ее http://exclusiveblog.ru/markup/problema-s-utf8-v-denwere вот статейка по этому поводу.